# Jsoup userAgent on Android - What does it mean?

Tags: android, jsoup, user-agent, mozilla, eofexception

I'm doing some `HTML` parsing using `Jsoup` in Android and I encountered some weird stuff(for me). Some sites work fine using the simple `Jsoup.connect(String).get()` method.

But in some other sites I **ALWAYS** get an `EOFException`. So i search and tackled the `userAgent` property , and when i use `Jsoup.connect(String).userAgent("Mozilla").get()` it work just fine.

Now what exactly that "mozilla" means? That my app could work only with devices that has `Mozilla` installed?

Comment: A little bit of googling doesn't hurt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent . Each site has to decide how it handles the `user-agent` header. It can reject the request if `user-agent` is empty or *unknown*  or has a wrong format or ... whatever. It can also simply ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time your web browser opens a web page, it sends a "request" for that page. Part of that request includes a series of "headers". Suppose you are using Firefox to open google then something like this will be sent to google

```
Host    www.google.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101   Firefox/45.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```

....
HTML responses in return is optimized for desktops / crawlers or in general for the browser (User-Agent) you are using. Sometimes it is totally different from the html response which is sent back for example to mobile agents (Android). The mobile version may not have anything that matches your Jsoup selectors. So with userAgent("Mozilla").get() your are telling that you wish to get the same response for your application which you see when you open google.com with a desktop browser.

Comment: Ahh i get it now. So it has nothing to do with any `Mozilla` app installed. Good. Thank you.